# How to make local single-user copy in Python API

Tags: python, scripting, blend-files, linked-data, data-blocks

How to use this button via Python.

[image]

`bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(object=True, obdata=True)` does not work for me at all,
`object.data.make_local()` makes library local without copying it, so all objects reference to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
object.data = object.data.copy()
```

makes localized copy of linked data-block.

Answer (score 0):

For those who has same question, this is a complete example:

````py
# get the original obj
original_obj = bpy.context.active_object
new_obj = original_obj .copy()

# create the data copy of the new_obj
new_mesh = original_obj.data.copy()
new_obj.data = new_mesh

# set the new_obj as active object for later process
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = new_obj

# make sure new_obj has single user copy
bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(object=True, obdata=True, material=False, animation=False)
```
````